# Inferring return types with `-> decltype`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

When using the C++11 arrow decltype statement, why does `boost::optional::operator*()` behave differently than `boost::optional::get()`?

Here's my code: (this *works*)

```
template<typename Fun, typename... Xs>
auto repeat_remove_optional(Fun f, std::string prompt, Xs&&... xs)
    -> decltype(f(prompt, xs...).get())
{
    auto x = f(prompt, xs...);
    if (x) return *x;
    prompt += "(Required!) ";
    while (true) {
        x = f(prompt, xs...);
        if (x) return *x;
    }
}
```

Use case is on some functions that prompt user with string and return `boost::none` if they enter escape during the input.

Using `-> decltype(*f(prompt, xs...))` won't compile, saying that `rvalue reference to type 'bool' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'bool': if (x) return *x;` (at both return statements there is this error).

In other places in my code, the two functions behave identically.  Why does this change here?

Usage:

```
boost::optional<bool> prompt_yes_no(const std::string& message);
bool continue = repeat_remove_optional(prompt_yes_no,
                                       "Are you sure you want to continue?"
```

Comment: It is not clear what it is you actually want to return. Do you want to move the object out of the optional? Do you want to copy it out? Do you want to return a reference to a value that is about to be destroyed?

Comment: Does decltype(*(f(prompt, xs...))) work?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Where is the pointer? Wat

Comment: @NicolBolas `auto x = fun(); return x;` should move the element twice.  If I replace `return *x;` with `return std::move(*x);` then it compiles correctly with `-> decltype(*f(prompt, xs...))`.  My question is why I have to change the returns based on the `-> decltype(...)`.

Comment: Don't you think the answer to your question depends on the `f` you're passing in? Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My guess is `f` returns an `optional` by value resulting in the `&&` qualified `operator*` being considered in the `decltype` expression - [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_operator_asterisk_move).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator*` has equivalent semantics with `value`, but not with `get`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_.html) for `boost::optional`, the signatures are:

```
T const& get() const;
T&       get();

T const& operator *() const&;
T&       operator *() &;
T&&      operator *() &&;

T const& value() const&;
T&       value() &;
T&&      value() &&;
```

Under the assumption that `f(prompt, xs...)` returns some `boost::optional<T>`, `decltype(*f(prompt, xs...))` is `T&&` whereas `decltype(f(prompt, xs...).get())` is `T&`.

```
auto x = f(prompt, xs...);  // `x` has type `boost::optional<T>`.
if (x) {
  return *x;  // `*x` has type `T&`.
}
```

Substitute `bool` for `T` and we've got your error of `rvalue reference to type 'bool' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'bool'`

In this case, `return *std::move(x)` would keep the expressions equivalent.

**NOTE**: `return std::move(*x)` would also work, but the subtle semantic difference is that you would be invoking `T& operator *() &` then performing `std::move` on the resulting `T&` as opposed to performing `std::move` on `boost::optional<T>&` then invoking `T&& operator *() &&`. The latter is more accurate, since the expression `*f(prompt, xs...)` invokes `T&& operator*() &&`.

**UPDATE** (Thanks [Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241631/praetorian) for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425796/inferring-return-types-with-decltype/34426356#comment56594280_34426356)): With the return type as specified, you're now returning a `T&&` into the contained value of `x` which is on the function stack. It would be best to `decay` the resulting type also: `std::decay_t<decltype(*f(prompt, xs...))>`.

Comment: This will get the code to compile, but it's now returning an rvalue reference to the value contained in the `optional` which will die when the function returns. He needs `remove_reference<decltype(...)>` in the return type.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Updated the answer to capture this, but I typically use `decay` rather than `remove_reference`.